# Detecting Keystroke Confusion

Tags: javascript

I've been having confusion regarding how to move an image using javascript. Any input would be helpful and i'm pretty sure it has to do with the addEventListener lines. The code is supposed to display an image tht can be controlled with the w a s and d keys but it won't move. Please don't judge me for sloppy coding, I'm only 14 :P

```js
var facing = "S";
var isMoving = false;

var imgSource = "Images/charlieIdle.png";

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

var charSpeed = 5;
var charX = 50;
var charY = 50;

var ctx;
function onKeyDown(event) {
  var keyPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  console.log(keyPressed);
  if (keyPressed == "W") {
    isMoving = true;
    facing = "N";
  } else if (keyPressed == "A") {
    isMoving = true;
    facing = "W";
  } else if (keyPressed == "S") {
    isMoving  = true;
    facing = "S";
  } else if (keyPressed == "D") {
    isMoving = true;
    facing = "E;"
  }
}
function onKeyUp(event) {
  var keyPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  if ((keyPressed == "W")||(keyPressed == "A")||(keyPressed == "S")||(keyPressed == "D")) {
    isMoving = false;
  }
}
function init() {
  var canv = document.getElementById("myCanv");
  ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
  canv.width = w;
  canv.height = h;
  window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
  window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyDown, false);
  return setInterval(draw,10);
}
function char() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img,charX,charY);
  };
  img.src = imgSource;
}
function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
}
function unloadScrollBars() {
    document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
function moveChar() {
  if (isMoving) {
    if (facing == "N") {charY -= charSpeed;}
    else if (facing == "W") {charX -= charSpeed;}
    else if (facing == "S") {charY += charSpeed;}
    else if (facing == "E") {charX += charSPeed;}
  }
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  char();
  onKeyDown();
  onKeyUp();
  moveChar();
}
init();
unloadScrollBars();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanv" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #888888"> </canvas>
    <script src= "library.js"></script>
    <script src= "game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing with this code? What is the expected result, and what your code does instead?

Comment: The code is supposed to display an image that can be controlled with the w a s and d keys. Sorry i wasn't very specific.

Comment: And the problem? What is going wrong? Also, please add the additional information to your post.

Comment: The problem is that it won't respond to any keyboard input.

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) always helps. Also when peeking at the console, there's an error message waiting for you. This is due to the "manual" `onKeyDown/Up` calls (in `draw`) without passing an event object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great first effort!  Reminds me of when I started coding :)

You biggest issue is that you have hooked up your event handlers with window.addEventListener but then you call them again manually in the draw() function.  window.addEventListener means that the function onKeyDown will be called automatically when a key is pressed or released so you can remove them from the draw() function.

```
function draw() {
  clear();
  char();
  //onKeyDown();
  //onKeyUp();
  moveChar();
}
```

If we then look at how you hook up your keypress events you've repeated onKeyDown twice.  So change the second one to onKeyUp.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);
```

Now you need to get used to using your debugger window (F12 in chrome). Running the code and debugging I found a small typo on this line...

```
facing = "E;"
```

and another one here...

```
else if (facing == "E") {charX += charSPeed;}
```

I also had to change your image (as I didn't have your one) so check that that part is working ok for you and I set the following CSS to make the canvas full screen (without the white space around it).

```
html,body { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Comment: Also consider what happens when your image goes off the screen (you can easily loose track of where it is).